# onClick change text color and back to color when clicking on another text

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2019

How to switch color between the six parameters, for example, when clicking (Home) turns text color to red and back to its same color black when clicking on (Projects) and when clicking (Timesheet) turns to red color and others remain same and so on with others, by using visual studio asp.net core 3.1

> The code for(_Layout.cshtml)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Bearu Firtas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body id="body">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-5">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Bureau Veritas</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark color-toggle" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark color-toggle" asp-area="" asp-page="/Proposel">Proposels</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark color-toggle" asp-area="" asp-page="/Project">Projects</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"> 
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark color-toggle" asp-area="" asp-page="/TimeSheet">TimeSheet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark color-toggle" asp-area="" asp-page="/Report">Reports</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark color-toggle" asp-area="" asp-page="/Invoice">Invoice By Month</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark color-toggle" asp-area="" asp-page="/Certificate">Certificates</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <!--<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2020 - BearuFirtas_App
        </div>
    </footer>-->

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

> the code for (site.js)

```
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.color-toggle');
nodes.forEach((node) => {
    node.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        nodes.forEach(ele => {
            if (ele === e.target) {
                ele.style.color = 'red'
            } else {
                ele.style.color = 'black'
            }
        })
    })
})
```

> The picture of layout,

[image: img of the layout]

Comment: So you basically want to highlight the text the one which gets clicked and the other should stay back to the default state.

Comment: as soon as I click on the text (for example clicking on the "Home" page) it changes its color to red, and on the other hand, when I click on another text (for example clicking on the "Projects" page) it changes its color to red but at the same time, the "Home" text returns back to its black color and so on.

Comment: Got it, I will add the answer below

Comment: I have added the answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `color-toggle` class to all those tabs in your navbar, and include the script below,

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.color-toggle');
nodes.forEach((node) => {
  node.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    nodes.forEach(ele => {
      if(ele === e.target){
        ele.style.color = 'red !important'
      } else {
        ele.style.color = 'black !important'
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="color-toggle">Home</div>
<div class="color-toggle">Projects</div>
<div class="color-toggle">Section 3</div>
<div class="color-toggle">Others</div>
```

Update 1: According to the comment, when using the code for `<a>` tag, you should use the `!important` in order to override the default styling of `<a>` tag.

Comment: when i add the color toggle to this code for example doesnt change anything in the running website.                                                                                                                 
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark color-toggle" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                       </div>

Comment: I would be able to help you in a much better way if you share a bit more of the code i.e. with more tabs so that I can reproduce the error and try to fix it

Comment: i have edited the code above as your solution, the color change only when adding **<div class=color-toggle>Home</div>** but when adding **<a class="nav-link text-dark color-toggle" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>**  it doesnt work when clicking the tab.

Comment: I have updated the code try using that, have also given the explanation for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

add something like this to your js:

```
document.getElementById("home").addEventListener("click", Red, false) //add id home to your home button
document.getElementById("projects").addEventListener("click", Black, false)//add id projects to your home button
document.getElementById("timestamp").addEventListener("click", Blue, false)//add id home to your timestamp button

function Red () {
  document.getElementById("body).style.color = "red";
}
function Black () {
  document.getElementById("body).style.color = "black";
}
function Blue () {
  document.getElementById("body).style.color = "blue";
}
```